# Interval scheduling

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Suppose we need always two nurses in a hospital during the period *[1, t]*. We have n nurses *(n1, n2, …, n)*. The nurses give the hospital their availability time Ex: Nurse k gives *{start_k, end_k}*. We have also an integer number I.

### Question

Is their two groups of nurses G1, G2 so that

```
|G1| <= I
|G2| <= I
```

and for each moment during [1, t] there are at least two nurses one from group1 and one from group2 available.

Note: we can let the nurse leave or enter whenever we think it gives a better result (considering their availability time).

### Sample IO

```
Input:

nurses_availability:
[ {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {5, 6}, {8, 10}, {6, 10}, {6, 8}, {7, 10} ]

I = 3
t = 10

Solution:

G1 = [ {1, 5}, {6, 10} ]
G2 = [ {1, 6}, {6, 8}, {7, 10}]
```

Comment: Did you try the problem on your own? Please mention your efforts and problems faced on doing so.

Comment: @AKSingh yes sure I've been trying for one week ;), but whatever I tried, failed at some point. I tried to convert this problem to a tree, and then find the shortest two paths, but got problems when building the tree, I believe there is a solution using dynamic programming, but I don't know how to start with it.
I would appreciate any ideas :)

Comment: You should your efforts on the question. I cannot remove the downvote unless the question is edited.